# Deleting line with sed not working in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sed, centos

I was using this command on CentOS in my bash script to remove line containing string from txt file:

```
sed -i -e "s/^$IPADDR/d" ips.txt
```

It was working fine in CentOS, but since i switched to Ubuntu 17.04 i get this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated `s' command
```

Any clue what could be wrong since command is ok?

EDIT:

```
IPADDR=$(shuf -n 1 ips.txt)
```

Content of proxy.txt is

```
IP:PORT
IP:PORT
IP:PORT
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `s` is a substitution command, expecting 3  /. For a deletion command just remove the 's''.

```
sed -i -e "/^$PROXY/d" file
```

Comment: Why is `.*` needed? `sed -i -e "/^$PROXY/d" ips.txt `works just fine. And why command worked on centos but not on Ubuntu? What I am missing here.

Comment: Actually I gave a random example sorry, I'll amend to be more clear.

Comment: Can you please explain why RED HAT (centos) is not showing error but ubuntu does. There is some difference in sed, more info?

Comment: I'm guessing just differing SED versions. The Ubuntu one is probably more modern and common.